# Any solution to the problem that nvidia X settings are not loading at startup?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 21.04, xorg.conf

I feel like monitors.xml are overriding the nvidia config, because if I execute `nvidia-settings --load-config-only` I see that It changes at least the color profile. It doesnt work to put on startup applications also. I feel that first xorg.conf gets executed and then override by monitors.xml. So my question for you is, how can you make Nvidia X Server Settings persistent after reboot (rtx 2080ti, 21.04, drivers 460)
[image]